# How do I apply a user defined function on a query in web2py DAL?

Tags: python-2.7, web2py

I am new to web2py frame work, I am building an application where by I need to determine records from the database which are a given period(say months) ago basing on the dates I recorded them with (Assignment_date), for example, listing cases which are 1 month, 2 months or 3 months old. so here is how I had done it but its not working in the model I define my tables and I have these two functions one converts a parsed date (date from the database) and the other does date difference basing on current system time and returns an epoch difference of the two dates.

```
stage =("Appeal","Investigation","Pre-Trial","Trial","Second Appeal")
status =("Draft","Open")
db.define_table('lfm_case',
            Field('title',requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
            Field('Assignment_date','date',requires=IS_DATE(format=T('%Y-%m-%d'))),
            Field('problem','text'),
            Field('reference_number',requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
            Field('institution'),
            Field('notes','text',requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
            Field('stage',requires=(IS_IN_SET(stage,multiple=False),IS_NOT_EMPTY()),default='Investigation'),
            Field('status',requires=(IS_IN_SET(status,multiple=False),IS_NOT_EMPTY()),default='Open'),
            Field('case_scope','integer',default=1,readable=False,writable=False),
            auth.signature)

 import datetime
def to_epoch(a):
        date_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(a), "%Y-%m-%d")
        epoch = int(date_obj.strftime('%s'))
    return epoch

def date_diff(b):
        current_date = datetime.datetime.now()
        current_epoch = int(current_date.strftime('%s'))
        diff = (current_epoch - to_epoch(b))
return diff
```

in the controller I have a function that tries to run a query to fetch all date whose date difference is <= the 26297435(that's a month) here is the function

```
def list_by_date():
        rows = db(date_diff(db.lfm_case.Assignment_date) <= 26297435).select(orderby=db.lfm_case.title)
return locals()
```

Below is my view

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
        {{for row in rows:}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{=row.Assignment_date}}</td>
            <td>{{=row.title}}</td>
            <td>{{=row.status}}</td>
        </tr>
        {{pass}}
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> db(date_diff(db.lfm_case.Assignment_date) <= 26297435).select(orderby=db.lfm_case.title)
> ```

First, `db.lfm_case.Assignement_date` is a DAL `Field` object, not a datetime object or string as required by `date_diff`. Second, the query that goes inside `db()` will ultimately be converted to SQL to be executed by the database engine, so it cannot involve the execution of arbitrary Python code -- it must be limited to what can be expressed via SQL.

Instead, because the database is storing date values, you should supply an actual date for comparison in the query (i.e., instead of calculating a timestamp, calculate the associated date). For example:

```
thirty_days_ago = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=30)
db(db.lfm_case.Assignment_date <= thirty_days_ago).select(...)
```

Alternatively, different databases provide their own functions for doing calculations with dates, so you can instead pass your own custom raw SQL as a DAL query:

```
db(custom_sql_string).select(db.lfm_case.ALL, ...)
```

Note, if the query passed to `db()` is just a raw SQL string not joined with any DAL `Query` objects via `&` or `|`, then the `.select()` must specify either some specific fields to select or `db.lfm_case.ALL` (which represents all fields) so that the DAL knows which table is involved in the query (it cannot determine that from a raw SQL string).

Comment: Thank you very much, it works fine and i'll go with the first option that you suggested

Comment: thirty_days_ago = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=30)
db(db.lfm_case.Assignment_date <= thirty_days_ago).select(...)

Comment: I just had to change the <= to >= because you realize all the dates of say year 2015 are less that (now()-30 days) so changing it to >= gives you only dates that are greater than or equal to (now() - 30 days) which i wanted then i can simply substitute 30 with a variable and parse any value to accupy that variable hence i can get dates say (IN 1 month), (IN 2 months) etc thank you so much so now how do i accept the your answer??